# Update pagination after hook_apachesolr_process_results()

Tags: search

Apache Solr Search
Version: 6.x-2.x-dev

I am using hook_apachesolr_process_results() to modify results of search. This returns fewer results than are indicated by displayed filters. Pagination is also configured for original search results, not those modified by hook.

My question is: Is there a way to modify the pagination due to modified results totals without deleting the excluded nodes from the index?

For example, if I execute search A, my pagination is set for a total of 100 results on 10 pages listing 10 results per page.

When the results of this search are modified by hook_apachesolr_process_results(), I now actually have only 15 results. But, my pagination is still set for 100 results.

I want to know how to reset the pagination for a total 15 results.

Thanks for any assistance anyone can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using hook_apachesolr_process_results() I figured it was better to use hook_apachesolr_update_index instead.

Following the guidance here: http://www.phase2technology.com/blog/filtering-apache-solr-search-results-based-on-dynamic-fields/

I am now able to create a filter using hook_apachesolr_modify_query that will return the correct results and pagination.